# Android notification start when ever I open app

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm

I am adding notification to my app, Everyting is working fine if app is shut down, and it fires notification exactly as i want, but when ever i start app, and on create is called notification fires. If i leave app and start app again, notification will fire again.

However, when ever i open my app notification fires. I do not want that behavior.

This is a code for for notifications and i put code in `onCreate`:
I know that i should move this from `onCreate` but where to move it?
Is it possible to check is alarm already set, if it is, then to not fire notification again.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000 , 1000 * 60 * 45, pendingIntent);
```

```js
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: ");

       
        Realm realm = null;
        try{
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            RealmResults<Drop> results = realm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("completed", false).equalTo("deleted", false).findAll();
            for(Drop current : results){
                if(isNotificationNeeded(current.getAdded(), current.getWhen(), current.isSwitchButtonchecked())){
                    fireNotification(current);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if(realm!=null){
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

```js
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TAG = "holaa";
    private long vrijemeStartAlarmUDevetSati = 1000*60*60*9; //milisecunds*secoonds*min*hours* - from 9h
    private long vrijemeAlarmDoJedanestSati = 1000*60*60*23;  //milisecunds*secoonds*min*hours* - to 23h
    Bundle bundle;
    int i = 0;


    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotificationService");
        Log.d(TAG, "NotificationService: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: ");

//realm database
        Realm realm = null;
        try{
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            RealmResults<Drop> results = realm.where(Drop.class).equalTo("completed", false).equalTo("deleted", false).findAll();
            for(Drop current : results){
                if(isNotificationNeeded(current.getAdded(), current.getWhen(), current.isSwitchButtonchecked())){
                    fireNotification(current);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if(realm!=null){
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void fireNotification(Drop drop) {
        i = i+1;

        String messageTitle = drop.getWhat();
        String messageNote = drop.getWhat_note();
        int ikonicaBojaNota = drop.getColorPickerRoudIcon();
       



        PugNotification.with(this)
                .load()
                .identifier(i)
                .title(messageTitle)
                .message(messageNote)
                .bigTextStyle(messageNote)
                .smallIcon(R.drawable.ic_drop)
                .largeIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .flags(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .autoCancel(true)
                .click(Main2Activity.class, bundle)
                .color(color)
                .simple()
                .build();
    }

    private boolean isNotificationNeeded(long added, long when, boolean switchButtonchecked){
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((now>when+ vrijemeStartAlarmUDevetSati) &&  (now < (when + vrijemeAlarmDoJedanestSati)) && switchButtonchecked == true){
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("notification", added);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //do nothing
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should cause the notification?

Comment: Im creating app where i save some data inside local data base including time when should notificaton be fired. Everyting is fine, but problem is when ever i open app and oncreate is called, notification fires

Comment: Please show the code that sets the time when the notification should occur.

Comment: I just add new code that shows what cause notification to be fired. But when app is shut down, everything is fine. Its fire notification every 45 min, just like i want. But, when i open app, it fire notification immediately, and every time when i open app

Comment: the first code snippet is in Activity's onCreate(), right? This tells the device to create a notification. If you do not want this then remove it.

Comment: Yes it is in onCreate(), that is what is causing notification to be fired. I do not know where to move it. If i move it, then maybe notification will not be created? Is it possible to check is notification already created once, and to not recreate notification again?

Comment: It looks like your service creates the notifications from the database. Why does your activity need to create notifications, too?

Comment: First im not pro with this, It is my first time im using notification so maybe im wrong. As i read so far, i need to start service to work on backgroud, and set up how often will service be fired. I do that with first code snippet wher i add service to be fired every 45 min. That is working fine while app is shut down, but when i start app, if all conditions meets then it fires notification when when ever i start app, and when ever onCreate() is called. I just pull conditions from database to check will i fire notification or not

Comment: P.s. You should show the class and method in each code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a service is independent of creating a notification. Your activity should only start the service. It should not create any notifications. Once your service starts, it is responsible for creating notifications.

Comment: Oh sorry, then i ask my question so wrong. My question should be how to start service only once. Well, it is the first time im using notifications, so im not very good with this. So, how to start service once, and never again?

Comment: @beginner Call startService()

Comment: @beginner see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. developer.android.com should be your first stop when learning Android programming.

Comment: Ohh, i will check that. Thanks. I also gogole now and there is lots of answer for my question. I totally mixed up services and alarms.